# How mark the end of a @ref reference?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document C++ code, and am writing a substantial amount of Doxygen doc for the code. In one place I'm making a list of groups in the code, and would like it to appear as follows:

> - [Control Module](http://example.com): the module that controls everything
> - [Slave Module](http://example.com): the module that is the slave of the [Control Module](http://example.com)

My documentation source looks like this:

> - @ref CM: the module that controls everything
>   - @ref SM: the module that is the slave of the @CM

But, problem: Doxygen seems to be reading the reference name as `CM:`, not `CM`, and thus can't find the reference. So, somehow I need to tell Doxygen where the reference name ends. (For example, if I were using Bash, and wanted to echo a variable string with an "s" as a suffix, I'd use `echo "${NOUN}s"`.)

As a workaround, I could add a space between the name and the subsequent colon, but that makes the resulting doc harder to read and I'd like to avoid it.

Under [Special Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html), the Doxygen manual includes the following hopeful-sounding information:

> Some commands have one or more arguments. Each argument has a certain
>   range:
>
> - If <sharp> braces are used the argument is a single word.
> - If (round) braces are used the argument extends until the end of the line on
>     which the command was found.
> - If {curly} braces are used the argument
>     extends until the next paragraph. Paragraphs are delimited by a blank
>     line or by a section indicator.

OK, that's all fine and good, but the documentation doesn't say, and I can't figure out, **where** those braces are supposed to go. Around the argument alone? Around the entire command and argument? Neither works, and I can't come up with an alternative that does work.

So, how do I indicate the end of a reference name to Doxygen? And if braces are the answer, where do they go?

Comment: The braces are there for the notational conventions, not as delimiter. The delimiter is the white space / newline. Question will always be what to use as delimiter / end of a "name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doxygen documentation you quote is describing the syntax of the *Doxygen documentation,* not of *sources* to be parsed by your use of Doxygen.

In other words, if <sharp> braces are used when describing a command, it takes a single word; and so on.

Looking at the documentation of [`@ref`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref):

> ```
> \ref <name> ["(text)"]
> ```

The `name` argument is in "sharp braces," and so it's just a single word. Unfortunately, Doxygen seems to interpret `:` as part of that word. Your best bet would be to introduce a space:

```
@ref CM : the ...
```

You could also try whether a zero-width character would break the word recognition:

```
@ref CM&zwnj;: the ...
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for Doxygen version 1.8.11:

```
\ref name "":
```

Apparently, the empty string triggers a fall-back to use the name argument before it.